# Azure Purview: tracking Lineage of columns in different layers

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake, azure-purview

I'm working in a databricks environment in combination with azure serverless pools. We have a common bronze, silver, gold delta architecture, where each layer is further displayed as an external table using synapse serverless pools in different schemas (bronze, silver, gold).

My question is, it seems possible to use Azure Purview scans to recognize data lakes, databases and so on. But since we are loading columns using databricks notebooks from each layer to the other, is it possible to use Azure Purview to track the lineage?
Like I have a column 'work_start_time' that is being slightly modified in each layer. Can I use Purview to track this column from bronze to gold?